# Transmission 2.94 not downloading

Tags: 20.04, ufw, bittorrent, transmission

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and then installed Transmission 2.94 since it worked fine on my 18.04.

It wasn't downloading so I searched and found that `sudo ufw status verbose` returned that it was Inactive.

So I enabled it with `sudo ufw enable`

Still not working. I looked in transmission and tested the port 51413, told me it was closed.
I opened it with `sudo ufw allow 51413`

Tested again and it tells me it's Open now.

But it doesn't work with magnet links or by downloading the .torrent.

Any idea ?

Result of `sudo ufw status verbose` :

```
brian@PC:~$ sudo ufw status verbose
État : actif
Journalisation : on (low)
Par défaut : deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
Nouveaux profils : skip

To                         Action      From
----                       ------      --
51413                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
51413 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ticking the "Pick a random port every time Transmission is started" box and restarting Transmission. You could try testing whether that worked by using [the official Ubuntu torrents](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#bittorrents).

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work either. When I restart it, the port is usually closed and I can't think of manually check if it's open or not and then open it up every time.
But yes, if there is no solution, I'll pick another torrent client.